# Laravel Time Difference Sum

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a basic table which captures all sign in and out of a member of staff.

I am using laravel for my back-end and im struggling how to get the total number of hours on site.

```
ID | in_time   | out_time | in_date    | out_date
1  | 21:22:49  | 21:46:05 | 2016-01-28 | 2016-01-28
2  | 08:12:12  | 14:12:01 | 2016-01-28 | 2016-01-28
```

See my query so far

```
$date1 = '2015-01-28';
$date2 = '2015-01-28';

$attendancehours = DB::table('staff_attendances')->whereBetween('in_date', array($date1, $date2))->where('id', $sID)
        ->get();
```

How would I output total hours on site for that daterange?

Comment: Not an answer to your question but it might be interesting for you to know that Laravel comes with [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/), which sole purpose is to format dates and generally make them easier to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to go about this are

1. Use Carbon see the documentation on [Difference](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference)

   Plenty of examples of this on their website
2. Assuming your using MySQL use [`timestampdiff`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

   SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');

   You can do this with a RAW query in Laravel something like

   ```
   $attendancehours = DB::select(
       DB::RAW('TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,CONCAT(in_date," ",in_time),CONCAT(out_date," ",out_time)'))->
       table('staff_attendances')->
       whereBetween('in_date', array($date1, $date2))->
       where('id', $sID)
       ->get();
   ```

Warning: I haven't tested the above but should work.

Comment: The first option should be the preferred as it doesn't involve raw (native) SQL statements which are in turn almost all not portable. `DB` also returns you a `Collection` but with `stdClass` instead of `StaffAttendance` model records (assuming that you have called your `Model` this way).